# What happens in these end-game situations?

Tags: carrom

This is intended to be a canonical question regarding possible endings of the game.

For each question, assume a single proper strike was made, and note where an improper strike would change the game outcome (beyond an additional point for the opponent).

### If the Queen has been covered:

1. What happens if I pocket my last C/m and the Striker?
2. What happens if I pocket my opponent's last C/m?
3. What happens if I pocket my opponent's last C/m and the Striker?
4. What happens if I pocket both players' last C/m?
5. What happens if I pocket both players' last C/m and the Striker?

### If the shot covers the Queen:

6. What happens if I pocket my last C/m and the Queen?
7. What happens if I pocket my last C/m, the Queen and the Striker?
8. What happens if I pocket my opponents' last C/m and the Queen?
9. What happens if I pocket my opponents' last C/m, the Queen and the Striker?
10. What happens if I pocket both players' last C/m and the Queen?
11. What happens if I pocket both players' last C/m, the Queen and the Striker?

### If the Queen is left on the board:

12. What happens if I pocket my last C/m, leaving the Queen?
13. What happens if I pocket my last C/m and the Striker, leaving the Queen?
14. What happens if I pocket my opponent's last C/m, leaving the Queen?
15. What happens if I pocket my opponent's last C/m and the Striker, leaving the Queen?
16. What happens if I pocket both players' last C/m, leaving the Queen?
17. What happens if I pocket both players' last C/m and the Striker, leaving the Queen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [ICF Laws of Carrom](http://icf-media.beepworld.de/laws-of-carrom.htm). Bracketed numbers in italics refer to specific rules that cover the questions.

---

### If the Queen has been covered:

**1. What happens if I pocket my last C/m and the Striker?**

You **lose** by 1/3* (+1**).

**2. What happens if I pocket my opponent's last C/m?**

You **lose** as normal.

**3. What happens if I pocket my opponent's last C/m and the Striker?**

You **lose** as normal (+1**).

**4. What happens if I pocket both players' last C/m?**

You **win** by 1/3*. For an improper stroke, you **lose** by 1/3* (+1**).

**5. What happens if I pocket both players' last C/m and the Striker?**

(*110/112*) You **lose** by 1/3* (+1**).

---

### If the shot covers the Queen:

**6. What happens if I pocket my last C/m and the Queen?**

(*97*) You **win** as normal, having covered the Queen. For an improper stroke, you **lose** by 3* (+1**).

**7. What happens if I pocket my last C/m, the Queen and the Striker?**

*Unsure!* You **lose** by 3* (+1**).

**8. What happens if I pocket my opponents' last C/m and the Queen?**

(*103*) You **lose** as normal, and the Queen is considered covered by your opponent.

**9. What happens if I pocket my opponents' last C/m, the Queen and the Striker?**

You **lose** as normal (+1**), and the Queen is considered covered by your opponent.

**10. What happens if I pocket both players' last C/m and the Queen?**

(*102*) You **win** by 1/3*. For an improper stroke, you **lose** by 3* (+1**).

**11. What happens if I pocket both players' last C/m, the Queen and the Striker?**

(*109*) You **lose** by 3* (+1**).

---

### If the Queen is left on the board:

**12. What happens if I pocket my last C/m, leaving the Queen?**

(*107*) You **lose** by 3*.

**13. What happens if I pocket my last C/m and the Striker, leaving the Queen?**

(*108*) You **lose** by 3* (+1**).

**14. What happens if I pocket my opponent's last C/m, leaving the Queen?**

(*106*) You **lose** as normal, and the Queen is considered covered by your opponent.

**15. What happens if I pocket my opponent's last C/m and the Striker, leaving the Queen?**

(*111*) You **lose** as normal (+1**), and the Queen is considered covered by your opponent.

**16. What happens if I pocket both players' last C/m, leaving the Queen?**

(*105*) You **lose** by 3*.

**17. What happens if I pocket both players' last C/m and the Striker, leaving the Queen?**

You **lose** by 3* (+1**).

---

* This is the value of the Queen: if the winning player did not cover the Queen, or is at 22+ points, they get 1 point. Otherwise they get the 3 points for covering the Queen.

** The opponent may claim 1 additional point as Due (you pocketed the Striker) and/or 1 additional point as Penalty (you made an improper stroke).

Comment: Not sure what the standard is for self-answering but I'll accept this in the meantime and change it as appropriate.