# If I pocket the queen and one opponent's C/m in the same shot, what happens?

Tags: carrom

If I'm playing black and I pocket the queen and a white C/m in a single shot, do I get a chance to cover the queen? Or does the queen come back on the board? Or does the queen go to the opponent?

Comment: Is this covered [here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/28732/15483)? I don't know enough about carrom to tell...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can continue and get a turn to pocket the cover provided the white coin was not the last coin on the board. 
If white coin was the last coin on the board then white wins the board. 4 points if his score is less than 22 and 1 point if score is more than 21.

Comment: This is incorrect. Player loses their turn when pocketing the opponents coin.

Answer (score 1):

Pardon the bump but the correct answer is:

Player loses their turn and the queen comes out. Any of the opponents pieces remain pocketed.

Actually this is hard to pin down. The [official rules](https://icf-media.beepworld.de/laws-of-carrom.htm) state that if a player pockets an opponents piece their turn is over. Since they would then not be able to cover the queen must therefore also come out. There seems to be no mention of any due or penalty, nor a specific rule covering this, so the pocketing of an opponents coin ending the turn appears to take precedent.

However according to [Master Of Games](https://www.mastersofgames.com/rules/carrom-rules.htm) website, this would count as a foul, the turn would end and the queen along with a penalty coin would be replaced. The pocketed coins would remain pocketed. The rules laid out on this site differ in many ways from the official ICF rule so take that into consideration.

Both rule sets state the turn ends and the queen is replaced, the only difference being whether or not the penalty is charged.