# What happens if I pocket both my own coin and my opponent's while covering the Queen?

Tags: carrom

I pocketed the Queen, and then in the covering strike I pocketed a coin of each player. What happens?

Comment: Can you please tell which game. The "identify-this-game" does not look apropriate here.

Comment: Could you confirm the game is indeed Carrom?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens in these end-game situations?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/28732/what-happens-in-these-end-game-situations)

Comment: @GendoIkari I don't think it's a duplicate of that as it can happen at times when the game isn't ending (the same question with "last coin" would be).

Comment: @Samthere Ok. The original question said "who will win" so I assumed it was the end of the game; but I know nothing about Carrom.

Comment: @GendoIkari Ah I see your point, I read that as asking "who wins the situation/who covers the queen", but your way is feasible too.

Answer (score 2):

Under normal circumstances, you count as having covered the Queen, but your opponent has a coin pocketed for free and your turn ends.

If the Striker was pocketed with it, you would pay the penalty for pocketing the Striker and then try to cover it again. However, since you pocketed the opponent's coin, you can't take another turn, so the Queen is put back on the board.

If it was one player's last coin, that player wins.

If it was both players' last coin, you win. If the Striker was pocketed with it, you lose.